# Huawei push API throws error saying token count is wrong in postman

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

Using push API continuously returns token count should within 1 and 1,000. Please find the API error in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: hey@ Krishna M i,You already have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible causes of this problem is, you have placed the “token” attribute in wrong place.

Solution:
Please keep your “token” attribute within the “message” object,.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5j8V.png)

For details, check the following documents:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-server-dev-0000001050040110

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your token is outside the message body, "token", "android" should be within the message body.

Please check the sample code [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/quickapp-access-push-kit)

Also, if you want to use more tokens (>1000), the best method is to invoke the API using App server and send messages in batches.